# How to make XAMPP recognize new font I add in my system

Tags: browser, fonts, xampp

I'm working on psd's to practice CSS but the problem is when I want to add a new font 
I download then install it on my system(windows 8.1 it helps) and when I restart the photoshop it recognize the font immediately but the font doesn't change in the browser so what can I do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time 
I realized that when I restart my pc the problem is solved
but it takes more than one restart I don't know why :(